# Variar valor de uma função de modal dentro de javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Tenho um campo de mudança de senha em um modal, nesse campo tenho uma função em java script que mostra a senha ao clicar no ícone, como estou em um modal a função funciona apenas no primeiro usuário da lista, pois, o código entende que existe somente um. Minha pergunta é como eu faço para variar o nome da function de acordo com o modal?

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--Campo Senha-->
                            <form method="POST">
                            <div class='input-group col-lg-6'>
                                <div class='input-group-addon'>
                                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type='password' name='senha' id="senha" class='form-control' value="senha" placeholder='Nova Senha' style="background-color: PeachPuff;" ></div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open " onclick="mostrar()"></button>
                            </form>
                            <script>
                                function mostrar(){
                                    var tipo = document.getElementById("senha");
                                    if(tipo.type == "password"){
                                        tipo.type = "text";
                                    }else{
                                        tipo.type = "password";
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>
                            <br>
                            <!--Fim Campo Senha-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é necessário criar uma função para cada situação. Isso seria péssimo. Use apenas uma função. Não use `id` para esse propósito, já que um `id` deve ser único em uma página. Pegue o elemento pela proximidade do botão clicado, como achar o elemento pelo `name` dentro do mesmo *container*.

> Apague o atributo `id="senha"` dos elementos, não é necessário.

Você consegue isso desta forma:

No `onclick`, inclua o parâmetro `this`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" onclick="mostrar(this)"></button>
```

E altere a função para:

```
function mostrar(e){
   var tipo = e.parentNode.querySelector("[name='senha']");
   if(tipo.type == "password"){
       tipo.type = "text";
   }else{
       tipo.type = "password";
   }
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function mostrar(e){
   var tipo = e.parentNode.querySelector("[name='senha']");
   if(tipo.type == "password"){
       tipo.type = "text";
   }else{
       tipo.type = "password";
   }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST">
 <div class='input-group col-lg-6'>
     <div class='input-group-addon'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'></span>
     </div>
     <input type='password' name='senha' id="senha" class='form-control' value="senha" placeholder='Nova Senha' style="background-color: PeachPuff;" ></div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" onclick="mostrar(this)"></button>
 </form>
```